# Validating File Name format in linux shell

Tags: linux, awk, sed, filenames

I will be receiving data files in a Linux directory.

I need to validate that the file names follow the following pattern "NNN-YYYYMMDD-NNNNNNNNN.pdf" where

- NNN stands for numeric value (0-9).
- "YYYYMMDD"  stands for valid date.  YYYY is the year, MM is the month (between 1-12) and DD is the day of the month (can have values between 01 to 31 depending on the month).
- NNNNNNNN is a numeric number (i.e. only 0-9 allowed).

What utility (SED, AWK etc.) and how  should I use to validate the file name.

Comment: you are looking for some manual started script, which validates a string?

Comment: You can do this using grep

Comment: Please show me how.

Comment: Can you give me a sample file that  you are expecting? Please post it to your question..

Comment: Does the year have to be the current year? Or current or prior? Or any from 0000 to 9999?

Comment: Assuming I get file name 001-20170131-000012345.pdf then it is a valid.  But if the file name is 0A1-20170131-000012345.pdf then it is invalid (because it has character "A" instead of a number in the name.

Comment: Any year is fine.

Comment: Please put your updates in the question, so that it's easy for everyone/anyone to see. Not here in the comments.

Comment: are there 8 or 9 N's before the .pdf? (you have 9 in your first pattern but 8 in the bulleted list) Is it always ending in .pdf?

Comment: is the `NNN` always 3 digits?

Comment: Do any of the existing answers solve your problem? If so, please indicate so with the checkmark, or else let us know what's missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This tests every file in the current directory, using bash's `[[` operator, against the pattern:

- start of string `^`
- 3 digits
- `-`
- 8 digits
- `-`
- 9 digits
- `.pdf`
- end of string `$`
- that the middle 8 digits evaluate to a valid date according to GNU date

You can adjust the assumptions above easily enough.

```
for f in *
do
  [[ $f =~ ^([0-9][0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]).pdf$ ]] && 
  date -d ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} &>/dev/null && 
  echo Valid: "$f"
done
```

Comment: nicer one, if year, month and day really always have the correct number count, maybe still remove the accidentally .pdf at the end :-)

Comment: Thanks  a lot.  I changed it to:  for f in "123-20170730-123456789.pdf"
do
  [[ $f =~ ^([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{8})-([0-9]{9}).pdf$ ]] &&
    date -d ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} &>/dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "Good File"
  else
    echo "Bad File"
  fi;
done

Comment: I have two (2) questions.  Question 1:  What is "~" in the expression.   Question 2:  Why does the following statement not work:  for f in "123-20170730-123456789.pdf"
do
  echo $f | grep '^([0-9]{3}-([0-9]{8})-([0-9]{9}).pdf$' &> /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "Good File"
  else
    echo "Bad File"
  fi;
done

Comment: @AlluSingh (1): Match a regex … (2) because you need to use *Extended" regex syntax and because you have not closed the first `(`. This do work:  `echo "123-20170730-123456789.pdf" | grep -E '^([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{8})-([0-9]{9}).pdf$'`

Answer (score 1):

sounds like:

```
TOCHECK=( "01-20170228-12345678" "012-20170230-012345678" "01-20170228-12345678" "123-20170730-012345678" )

for CHECK in $(seq 0 $(( ${#TOCHECK[@]}-1 )) ); do
    PARTS=( $(echo ${TOCHECK[$CHECK]} | sed "s/-/ /g")   )   
    echo -ne "\nchecking "
    echo "\"${PARTS[@]}\""
    echo "\"${PARTS[0]}\""
    echo "\"${PARTS[1]}\""
    echo "\"${PARTS[2]}\""

    if echo ${PARTS[0]} | grep "[0-9]\{3\}" ; then
        echo first part ok
    fi

    if echo ${PARTS[2]} | grep "[0-9]\{9\}" ; then
        echo last part ok
    fi  

    date --date="${PARTS[1]}"
    RES=$?
    echo $RES
    if [ 0$RES -eq 0 ]; then
        echo date OK
    fi  
done
```

(just some conceptual idea, of course to be modified)

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to use regexps. The validation is 2 steps: regexp matching and date validation. Here's a Python implementation:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys 
import re
import datetime

def validate(filename):
    match = re.match(r"[0-9]{3}-([0-9]{8})-[0-9]{8}\.pdf", filename)
    if not match:
        return False
    datestr = match.group(1)
    try:
        datetime.date(int(datestr[:4]), int(datestr[4:6]), int(datestr[6:8]))
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if validate(sys.argv[1]):
        print(":-)")
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print(":-(")
        sys.exit(1)
```

Usage: `python validate.py FILE`

One can probably use grep and date to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

One basic solution, using `grep`.  Doesn't do the detailed date checking aspect, instead merely checks it's numeric.

```
if ls|grep -vE '^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{8}\.pdf$'; then
    echo some bogus files found
else
    echo all good
fi
```